# Windows application to run continously

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on c# winforms.
after installing the application, if I keep the application open everyday without closing it,i want it to refresh data automatically.
I am using datetimepicker and getting data from files.
if the files are added into the folder it should be automatically update n keep running the application. Also wanted date to update everyday if application is open all the time.
Please help.

Comment: if you are just wanting to wait for files (to update data), use [FileSystemWatcher Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Update with no restart?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "update".

Comment: yes application will be open all the time

Comment: I think you're meaning "update" as something akin to "refresh" rather than "update" as in "install a later version". But might be clearer if you rephrase to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-manage-updates-for-a-clickonce-application?view=vs-2017, this should clarify some of the update strategy for you.

Comment: You need a [service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer) to do the job.

Comment: Well we have a pretty large range of guess in the comment, this is a sign of an unclear question. Please read [ask] and try to reformulate your question. With clear context about the application, for now "datetimepicker" and "data from files" look not related to your question.

Comment: 1. Use `folderWatcher` to monitor on folder file change which will notify your application , Use `timer` in application which you can use for updating `DateTime`. 2. You can achieve this both in `Winforms` or `WindowsService`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the timer control to achieve this. you can set interval time property.

> if the files are added into the folder it should be automatically
>   update n keep running the application

For this use FileSystemWatcher Class.

Answer (score -1):

Have you thought of writing a Windows Service which can run continuously and do all the update?This Windows app can just consume the Windows Service and whenever opened,will fetch the latest data.Simple!